# how to make bar graph of a covariance matrix with ggplot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

For the following covariance matrix

```
ds <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="
        Intercept        timec       timec2        timec3
    1.737039978  0.092280863 -0.041651389  2.682618e-03
        0.092280863  0.627165049 -0.120993155  6.208261e-03
      -0.041651389 -0.120993155  0.026098510 -1.416538e-03
       0.002682618  0.006208261 -0.001416538  7.949634e-05
")
```

I would like to create a bar graph that represents values as bars arranged in the same way as in the matrix. I try this

```
d <- melt(d)
p<- ggplot(d, aes(x=variable, y=value, label=value))
p<- p+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
p<- p+ facet_grid(variable~.) 
p<- p+ geom_text()
p
```

But it doesn't distribute the values properly in the graph.

## Questions:

How would I create a bar graph for such matrix so that each value is represented as an individual bars and they are arranged in the same pattern as the values in the matrix?

[image]

How would

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to create a variable ('id'), which can be used as `id.vars` in `melt` and as 'row variable' in `facet_grid`. You may also have a look at the `facet_grid` argument `scales = "free_y"`

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

ds$id <- 1:nrow(ds)
d <- melt(ds, id.vars = "id")

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(id ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, @Henrik! I forgot all about this trick of creating extra variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about visualizing a covariance matrix uses a heatmap, created in ggplot using `geom_tile(...)`.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)       # for melt(...)
library(RColorBrewer)   # for brewer.pal(...)

d      <- melt(cbind(id=colnames(ds),ds),id="id")
colors <- brewer.pal(11,"Spectral")

ggplot(d, aes(x=id, y=variable, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  geom_text(aes(label=round(value,4),color=factor(sign(value))))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  labs(x="variable",y="variable")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low=colors[10],mid=colors[6],high=colors[2],
                       midpoint=0, 
                       limits=c(-max(d$value),max(d$value)))+
  scale_color_manual(guide="none",values=c("red","blue"))+
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: IMO you should select the other answer (from @Henrik) as the preferred answer, as it answers your question, while mine does not, really. I just thought you or others might find it useful to see another way to visualize covariance.

Comment: Sorry, in and out wifi. Your way gave me some new ideas of implementing what I want, so I slightly prefer it. But I take your point. I thought I could indicate two valid answers.